# How do I store some object on server-side with Snap Framework?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

That question was already asked in 2010, but I figure there might be a better answer today.
Basically I need to store some kind of object and access it in every request, ideally I want to be able to change that object from within a request (I guess an MVar or IORef will do for that).

The snaplet tutorial seems to indicate that it's possible, but it mostly explains how to use snaplets (that's what that tutorial is for after all), and doesn't really explain how this "App" object works or even is stored. I have no idea how to apply that to my case, where I have no need of snaplets (I'm making an API, so I don't even need Heist).

So given the default code :

```
site :: Snap ()
site = do
  ifTop (writeBS "hello world") <|>
    route [ ("stuff/:param", someHandler) ] <|>
    dir "static" (serveDirectory ".")
```

How do I change this to "register" some object somewhere that I could use in someHandler ? The answer from 2010 is just to partially apply it to every handler, which would work, but the Snaplet tutorial makes me think there must be a better way.

Comment: Can you add a link to the answer you're referring to?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903205/how-do-i-maintain-a-server-side-state-with-snap-framework

Comment: Almost all of the snap functions have return type `MonadSnap m => .. -> m X`. So just make an instance `MonadSnap m => MonadSnap (ReaderT m)` (if it doesn't exist already) and you don't have to explicitly pass the environment around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section "Working with State" in the snaplet tutorial they explain how to work with local state. If you look at the second code piece in the section called "Snaplet Overview" above that, you can see how they're setting up the state when they initialise the data type for it, using Lens.

Not sure how familiar you are with these things, but `Lens` lets you access (ie read/write/adjust) pieces of data within larger values. The entire state of the server in this case is represented as one blob of data (a record type value), which is initialised when the server is.

Note this: `_companyName :: IORef B.ByteString` <- is a piece of state that you can mutate in the example, and in the section "Working with state" that's just what they do. They have an example that takes an HTTP GET or POST to that URL, and either updates it with the new "name" param (POST) and returns the new state, or if it's a GET, it just returns the current state.

Comment: Allright so basically you need to make your whole app into a Snaplet to get a State, if I understand correctly. Seems to be working, I assume that won't impact performances since I don't really use snaplets, just the one ? Not that it matters much in my case, just curious

Comment: My understanding of Snap is, since a certain version, **everything** is built with snaplets which are the base level abstraction for any application-programmer level concerns. This provides modularity and is very efficient. Lenses are extremely lightweight data access on records which are also extremely basic. Snaplets are, at their core, about state, so this would be the canonical way to get state into your snap application. It's fast and efficient, from my understanding, but why not do some profiling :)